# Как сделать анимацию через JS

Tags: анимация, javascript

В общем мне надо медленно уменьшить прозрачность. Проблема в том, что j++ не работает с десятичными числами. Короче аналог fadeIn в jQuery

```
for(var j = 0.70; j < 0.90; j++){   
this.style.background = 'rgba(250,250,250,' + j + ')'
 }
// Это не правильно, но так понятнее будет , что я хочу сделать
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var j = 70; j < 90; j++){
    this.style.background = 'rgba(250,250,250,' + (j/100) + ')'
}
```

**UPD2**
**UPD3** (небольшую ошибку сделал).
Но лучше

```
var j = 70, me = this;
var f =  function f () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        j++;
        me.style.background = 'rgba(250,250,250,' + (j/100) + ')';
        if (j < 90) {
            f();
        }
    }, 100);
};
f();
```

Comment: @Антон Мухин у меня мигает теперь

Comment: Что мигает?)
И какой браузер.

Comment: Ну я поставил твою функцию на onmouseover и теперь он становится то ярче то темнее. Браузер Хром. Да и в первом варианте все равно быстро очень получается(

Comment: Что-то не увидел проблемы
http://jsfiddle.net/GF6pS/

Comment: анимация корректно работает ТОЛЬКО через setInterval

Comment: Интересно, что не так с setTimeout?

Comment: Так вы по 100 раз будете создавать таймер, куда эти расходы?

Comment: Да, согласен. Не согласен только с корректностью. Так оно нормально отрабатывает, только с не нужными дополнительными расходами.

Comment: Некорректно - это возникшие баги из-за переполнения чего-нибудь там :-)